# How to get entities in Tweets using Elliot Haughin's Twitter API with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter

I am using with using Elliot Haughin's Twitter API with Codeigniter. i want to get the entities for tweet.
Here is my code

$user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/user_timeline', array('include_entities' => 'true', 'count' => '2'));

But it does not show the entities. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

How about adding a screen_name like so:

```
$user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'biz', 'include_entities' => 'true', 'count' => '2'));
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question. Besides, statuses/user_timeline assumes the calling user when screen_name is omitted, so the code in the question is valid.

Comment: I stand corrected, Tom. It doesn't seem to me there's enough information in the question to determine whether he's properly implemented Haughin's API, i.e. has he set $tokens?

Comment: He wants to get the tweet entities and judging by his question he's not getting any. I'm not a user of the API that's mentioned, so I cannot help in this case.